# When having both onEdit and onOpen registered triggers, only onOpen works

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote two scripts, both using registered triggers. The first of them is an onEdit() function, that analyzes the data changes and uses my mail account to send automated information based on that data to a company alias. It works properly.

The other one is an onOpen() function adding a custom menu that can be used to add custom-filled rows to the spreadsheet and also using my mail to send the info on the data of that newly inserted row. It also works like a charm.

However, when I have both of these functions in one project, both in separate script files, only onOpen() function works, onEdit() one no longer triggering at all when the spreadsheet is edited.

The names of these scripts are different and I see nothing that could cause this behavior. Could anybody help me figure out if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my issue and would like to share it here for anybody looking for an answer.
It turned out to be an authorization issue. My scripts were used in couple of different projects, but each one of them had the same name. Adding to that some test spreadsheets I made to test some solutions, each of them again using script projects with the same name eventually led to my account authorizing ~ 15 scripts of the same name to use my google account. This made google confused and resulted in these scripts working only one at a time.

I fixed this by removing all registered triggers and removing the authorization for them from my google account. I then created separate projects, each named differently, and pasted my functions in them. Now all my functions work properly, regardless of whether they are used withing the same script file or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a spreadsheet with a script and set up both [simple-triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) (onOpen and onEdit) and both [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for these events. All 4 fired normally.

Here's the full code I used to test:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('onOpen').addItem('test', 'alertOnOpen').addToUi();
}

function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.setValue('onEdit');
}

function triggerOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('triggerOpen').addItem('test', 'alertTriggerOpen').addToUi();
}

function triggerEdit() {
  alert('triggerEdit');
}

function alertOnOpen() { alert('onOpen'); }

function alertTriggerOpen() { alert('triggerOpen'); }

function alert(msg) { SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg); }
```

Here's my installable-trigger setup:
[image: triggers setup]

By the way, you mention [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) but kept calling them 'onOpen' and 'onEdit', which are the names for [simple-triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). When using installable triggers you should pick different names, to avoid confusion and double execution of the same function on different authorization scopes. Please read the linked documentation for clarification and more in-depth explanation.

Lastly, here's the [link of the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jSVfCzls_88DwMn-tvJ5_CMPR2zHI5dE53kxRRuI4MY/edit#gid=0) I tested in, if you want to make a copy (and setup the installable triggers yourself)

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. When I moved both functions to the same script file, it works correctly, which fixes my issues. Still, I don't understand why they do not work when each of them is stored in a separate script file within the same project. 

As I write a lot of scripts for use in a single spreadsheet, having each of them in a separate file makes it much easier for me to find and edit the one I'm interested in. Having all of them simply thrown into a single script file makes it much more difficult. 

Could you check if these functions work for you in separate script files?

Comment: Works fine. Tested it again, you can checked my testing spreadsheet linked in the answer. I created a 2nd file and even a 2nd project, it all run just fine if I don't conflict names.

Comment: I checked and it indeed works fine in your file. Yet, when I use exactly the same setup on my side, onEdit trigger stops working. Unfortunately I can't share the spreadsheet as the data is too sensitive... For now I will just put all the functions in the same script file, as this is a working solution, even if not ideal. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the notifications to be "immediate" rather than daily (rather than the next day) when you are creating the triggers you might see that they have been failing.

You could also look in the Execution Transcript in the script editor for any errors.

There are also "edits" that the onEdit trigger doesn't pick up - search for "onEdit" in the [GScript issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). Undoing a delete is one that caught me out.

Comment: I don't use notifications at all, and the execution transcript does not even register any info on the execution process of the onEdit fuctions, meaning it is not triggered at all. There are no errors and both functions work correctly on their own as long, as they are not used simultaneously in the same project.